# Anyone have details on NE PA slang term “Grauner”?

Tags: slang, demonyms, pennsylvanian-english

My dad grew up in the Anthracite coal region of NE Pennsylvania. NEPA is known for a pretty unique accent, phonetically more Midwest than Philadelphia or New York, and a lot of vocabulary that developed from the mix of Eastern and Southern European immigrants that came to the area to work as coal miners.

One word that was used commonly in my family but never really explained was “Grauner” (spelling not confirmed, could be Grawner or Graner). It’s a demonym referring to the nationality of some families in the town including my dad’s. People refer to the “Grauner Church” to distinguish the parish from the 6 other Catholic churches in town (the Irish Church, the Russian Church, the Lithuanian Church, etc).

Closest I can tell it means either Slovenian/Yugoslavian or Slovak based on our family census records, but no idea the origin of the term. It doesn’t seem to be known/used outside of their hyper-specific region.
Anyone ever hear this term before or know any other info? It’s been a mystery to me since I was a child!

Answer (score 1):

"Grauner" is, [according to Wikipedia,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graun_im_Vinschgau) the German demonym for residents of the city of **Graun im Vinschgau.** This city is currently a part of a mostly German-speaking region of Italy, but it was originally a part of Austria-Hungary.

I'm not sure how old this demonym is, however, and it seems very obscure, so I'm not sure if this is actually the origin of the usage you cite.